# Реализация getline для своего класса string

Tags: c++, строки

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста, проблема в функции `getline()`,которая принимает 2 аргумента: **Входной поток, из которого следует извлечь строку** и ***строка, в которую считываются символы из входного потока***. Есть дополнительный 3й аргумент , но я его не использую.

Моя проблема , что я реализую собственный класс `String` и `getline()` конечно же ругается на второй аргумент, так как он не тот, который ему нужен, а мой пользовательский.

не могли бы мне подсказать, как правильно реализовать метод `getline()` с моим аргументом?

Я надеюсь, что мой класс String, я реализую правильно, поэтому , я не показываю его код из-за объема и ненадобности. Проблема в методе.

Код , где я использую `getline()`:

```
string str; // typedef мой класс Sring для удобства
    int readCount = 0;
    int n = atoi(num);
    readRecord.open(fileName);
    if (_access(fileName, 0) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error:FILE NOT FOUND" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else {

        while (std::getline(readRecord, str))// здесь именно моя проблема  
        {
            readCount++;
            lines.push_back(str);
        }
```

Comment: Только наследоваться от `std::basic_string` либо не использовать стандартный getline

Comment: @vp_arth скорее всего не использовать стандартный `getline()`, можете подсказать его реализацию с моим аргументом, в интернете не могу откопать нужное

Comment: Функция должна вычитывать из потока в вашу строку символы до разделителя строк.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно реализовать свою функцию. Вариант первый - берете стандартную, читаете в стандартную строку, а потом присваиваете эту строку вашей.

Вариант второй - читаете по символу, пока не встретите '\n', и добавляете их в свою строку. Тоже ничего сложного. Правда, не самый эффективный способ, но, думаю, для обычных применений вполне годится. Можно в принципе работать прямо с `rdbuf`, это быстрее, но и писать сложнее.

Поскольку ничего о внутренностях вашей строки вы не написали, никаких набросков кода привести не могу.

Comment: спасибо,за ответ, вы были правы, получилось реализовать самому